# UINavigationItem leftBarButton is hidden behind it's background

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a UINavigationBar with a custom background and my own back button. I did the following to try achieve this.

```
//custom background
UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar.png"]] autorelease];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:background atIndex:0];

//custom back button
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
[customBarItem release];
```

The back button always works, but it can only be seen if I don't apply my custom background. Could someone please point out how to achieve both?

Thanks in advance.
Ricky.

Answer (score 1):

You can set background image of navigation bar by using this

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx 
{
    if([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])
    {
        UIImage *image;


        image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_img"];


        CGContextClip(ctx);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, image.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx,
                           CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage); 
    }
    else 
    {        
        [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];     
    }
}  
@end
```

Comment: Thanks saadnib, but what would happen if I want to change the background throughout my app?

Comment: Sorry I meant a situation where I want a navigation bar's background to change to different images throughout the app?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Category)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.navImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Every time I want to change the background of the bar, I change the delegate's navImage property and call `-setNeedsDisplay` on my navigation bar.

Thanks for your help.